# Wix custom javascript fires only on page refresh

Tags: javascript, pageload, velo

Working with Wix webite, i added a custom code with some javascript to change some elements.
Basically strip commas and transform words to links.

Code works fine in my simple test page.
The wix website though, only fires the js by reloading the page.
I need it to fire on page first load.

`

```
window.onload = (event) => { 
 const mystring = document.querySelectorAll('#comp-id p span');
 for (const taglines of mystring) {
      const words = taglines.innerHTML.split(', ');
      for ( i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        var swords = words[i].replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase().normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "");
        words[i] = `<a href="http://example.com/${swords}" class="menuintag">${words[i]}</a>`;
      }
      taglines.innerHTML = words.join(' ');
    }
};
```

`

tested :

```
 //window.onload = function() 
//  window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function()
```

i also tried directly in the built-in editor, mainpage.js

no success yet...

How can i do it please?

Comment: I think wix had some sort of custom syntax like `$w.onReady(() => {
    doWhatEver();
});`

Comment: that would be what they call the "built-in" editor. But doesn't work there either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within a Wix site, you'll need to use Velo APIs to work with page elements instead of standard JavaScript functions.

Take a look at their [Hello World example](https://www.wix.com/velo/example/hello-world) to see how it works.

See the [Velo API Reference](https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/$w). You'll want to start with the Wix Editor Elements ($w) section.

Answer (score -2):

I've never used Wix before.

But Give this block a try.
There are a few different `onLoad` methods for better backwards compatibility

```
function onLoad() { 
 const mystring = document.querySelectorAll('#comp-id p span');
  for (const taglines of mystring) {
       const words = taglines.innerHTML.split(', ');
       for ( i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
         var swords = words[i].replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase().normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "");
         words[i] = `<a href="http://example.com/${swords}" class="menuintag">${words[i]}</a>`;
      }
      taglines.innerHTML = words.join(' ');
    }
}


if (window.attachEvent) { window.attachEvent('onload', onLoad); }
else if (window.addEventListener) { window.addEventListener('load', onLoad, false); }
else { document.addEventListener('load', onLoad, false); }
```

Comment: we are not running browsers from the 90's

Comment: thanx for code, but didn´t go..

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).